# Selecting the proper fields from Get-WebApplication (IIS)

Tags: powershell, iis, iis-7.5

I was looking to get a list of IIS Websites along with their assigned Applications.

This is where I'm having difficulties:

```
Get-WebApplication | select itemxpath

ItemXPath
---------
/system.applicationHost/sites/site[@name='siteServices' and @id='4']/application[@path='/siteServices']
/system.applicationHost/sites/site[@name='0-site.com' and @id='19']/application[@path='/DCS']
/system.applicationHost/sites/site[@name='0-site.com' and @id='19']/application[@path='/DCSWebService']
```

What I'd like to do is extract "@name" and "@path" and place them in separate tabs. Is there a way of doing this more elegantly than using a regex string manipulation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, it's not exactly elegant per se but it does what I wanted:

```
Get-WebApplication | select @{L="ApplicationName";E={$_.path.replace("/","")}}, @{L="Website";E={$_.itemxpath.split("'")[1]}}
```